# Right way to terminate testing mongodb server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing

We are using `mongodb-prebuilt` package for perform unit/integration testing (CI/CD) for the developed software, which performs interaction with mongodb database.

Common use case is following: launch testing mongodb server with prebuild package, perform test suite execution and then terminate server. First and second items are done easily, but third one causes some problems.

If `mongodb-prebuilt`-started server had not been terminated, test runner will hang forever. Instead, if try to terminate server by `testConnection.command({ shutdown: 1 })` command, then `unhandledRejection` fires, which refers on closed connection - which of course had been forcefully closed by stopping the server.

Which is right way to dispose `mongodb-prebuilt` at `afterAll` test section? Test engine is `jest`, but it does not matter strongly.
Example code here:

```
import { MongodHelper } from 'mongodb-prebuilt';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

describe('Test suite', () => {
    let testConnection;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const mongodHelper = new MongodHelper(['--port', "27018"]);
        await mongodHelper.run();
        testConnection = await MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27018/admin`);
    });
    afterAll(async () => {
        await testConnection.dropDatabase();
        await testConnection.command({ shutdown: 1 });
        await testConnection.close();
        testConnection = null;
    });
    /* Here follows some test suite that uses testConnection  */
}
```

There was some attempts to solve problem:

1) Don't await `testConnection.command({ shutdown: 1 })`-generated promise, and instantly initiate client connection closing - it works on some machines, but most likely depends on execution speed, so works unstable.

2) Because of client connection termination at the end of the tests does not matter strongly - it's possible to setup `process.on('unhandledRejection', ...)` handler in `afterAll` section and just mute exception - works well, but seems to be ideologically incorrect

So, maybe is there stereotypical solution for original task?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: suggesting use some mock packages instead live `mongodb` is not appropriate at all, since developed software is specific adapter for `mongodb` and should respect all aspects of live database, including timings, admin commands and so on

Answer (score 0):

Most convenient solution for original problem is using `mongo-unit` npm package, which despite the name, provides API for automated integrated testing with real mongodb prebuild server, including launch and stopping it: https://github.com/mikhail-angelov/mongo-unit/

Gauge test suite with  `mongo-unit` looks like following:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import mongoUnit from 'mongo-unit';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

describe('MongoDB-based test suite, () => {
    let testConnection;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const connectionUrl = await mongoUnit.start({ dbName: 'admin' });
        testConnection = await MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl);
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await testConnection.dropDatabase();
        await testConnection.close(true);
        await mongoUnit.stop();
        testConnection = null;
    });

    /* Test suite goes here */

});
```

Package also allows to select initial database at start, and perform clear mongodb server process stopping at end of test suite.